# MySQL - 'field' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im using Laravel framework and it gives an error with the DB

Error message:

> [2016-04-25 06:07:34] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:  General error: 1364 Field 'remarks' doesn't
>   have a default value' in ...

The field 'remarks' has a default value of 'None' set in PHPMyAdmin. I dont understand why does it gives an error when it has a default value set. I believe that 'None' is a string value so it's not like a NULL value.

```
$aId = DB::table('attachments')->insertGetId([ 'document_type_code'=>$document_id, 'report_no'=>'report '.$document_id, 
'file_attachment_link'=>$filepath, 'file_attachment_upload'=>$file->getClientOriginalName(), 'uploaded_at'=> $now, 'uploaded_by' => 1, 
//Auth::user()->id 'version_number' => 1, ]);
```

Comment: Please show your code!!

Comment: $aId = DB::table('attachments')->insertGetId([
                'document_type_code'=>$document_id,
                'report_no'=>'report '.$document_id,
                'file_attachment_link'=>$filepath,
                'file_attachment_upload'=>$file->getClientOriginalName(),
                'uploaded_at'=> $now,
                'uploaded_by' =>  1, //Auth::user()->id
                'version_number' => 1,



            ]);

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code there

Answer (score 1):

`None` is not a default string value. It means that there is no default value set.

You can either pass a value in your `INSERT` statement or alter the table to actually hold a default value for the column.

You can use this `sql` statement to alter the table

```
ALTER TABLE attachments MODIFY COLUMN `remarks` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'something';
```

Or do it from `PhpMyAdmin`

Comment: I am getting same error. Please help me- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322806/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1364-field-photo-doesnt-have-a-default-value

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit the tables directly. You have your model for that.
Generate a new migration and set you field to be nullable:

`$table->string('name', 50)->nullable();`

and then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: I am getting Same error. Please help me-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322806/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1364-field-photo-doesnt-have-a-default-value