# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'photo' doesn't have a default value in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

I am trying to upload users photo during registration, but I am getting this error, I searched online and founded possible solutions did not work for me.  I am using sentinel package for advanced authentication. Please anyone help me .
Here is my controller-

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'user_name' => 'unique:users|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
    //upload image
    if ($file = $request->file('photo')) {
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension() ?: 'png';
        $folderName = '/uploads/users/';
        $destinationPath = public_path() . $folderName;
        $safeName = str_random(10) . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move($destinationPath, $safeName);
        $request['photo'] = $safeName;
    }

    // $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($request->all());
    $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($request->all());
    // dd($user);
    //$activation = Activation::create($user);

    $role = Sentinel::findRoleBySlug('member');

    $role->users()->attach($user);
    //$this->sendEmail($user, $activation->code);
    //return redirect('/login');
    return ('You have seccsessfully registered. Now login to start');
}
```

And form input-(with enctype="multipart/form-data" top of the form)

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="sponsor-row">
        <label for="sponsor_input"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></label>
        <input type="text" name="sponsor" id="sponsor_input" class="sponsor-input" placeholder="Sponsor"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="photo-row">
        <label for="photo_input"></label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="photo-input"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My User Model is:

```
<?php
```

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_name','email', 'password', 'phone', 'location', 'sponsor', 'photo',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

My Migration Code is:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('location');
        $table->string('sponsor');
        $table->binary('photo')->nullable();
        $table->text('permissions')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_login')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->unique('email');
    });
```

Comment: Database table  column photo need a default value like null

Comment: just set a default value for your `photo` column in your table typically `null`

Comment: Post Your Sentinel Model & Migration Code..

Comment: Here is my User Model- protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_name','email', 'password', 'phone', 'location', 'sponsor', 'photo',
    ];

Comment: And here is migration - Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('location');
            $table->string('sponsor');
            $table->binary('photo')->nullable();

Comment: $table->text('permissions')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_login')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->unique('email');
        });

Answer (score 3):

> General error: 1364 Field 'photo' doesn't have a default value

This error means that there is a column `photo` in the associated table that doesn't have a default value and you are not including that column in your insert query.

To solve it, either make that column `NULLABLE` or pass some value to insert in that column.

Comment: And that it isn't NULLABLE

Comment: if change to default value null. It's insert others values except 'photo'. But, I want to insert photo. I tried by adding to insert query $request->request->add(['photo' => $safeName]); Or $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate(array_merge($request->all(),['photo' => $safeName]));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322806/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1364-field-photo-doesnt-have-a-default-value

Answer (score 3):

if you are using latest version of laravel go to config/databse.php and in connection there is `mysql` array:-

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false, 
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

By default strict is true and set to make it false.(2nd last key in mysql array) Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
$request['photo'] = $safeName
```

You can not directly put values like associative array in `Request Class Object`
And that's why there is no value for `photo`, and it is giving your error for SQL Insert.

You should do something like this

```
$request->request->add(['photo' => $safeName]);
```

or Better way

```
$user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate(array_merge($request->all(),['photo' => $safeName]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you mysql version, if you have greater than 5.6.39 then. please go to variables and find sql mode and remove STRICT_TRANS_TABLES[image]